# Searching for theorems characterizing when $O_p(G)$ is trivial / non-trivial

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $p$ be a prime.

Let $O_p(G)$ be the $p$-core of $G$.

> Are there any theorems known saying something like
>
> $O_p(G)$ is trivial, if and only if ... and
>
> $O_p(G)$ is non-trivial, if and only if ..., respectively ?

I am especially interested in the case $p=2$.

> If not, criteria ensuring that $O_p(G)$ is trivial / non-trivial would also be interesting.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many such theorems. By the way, I would say that your definition of $p$-core may be non-standard if you are using it to denote the largest normal $p$-subgroup of $G$. I think many people would use $p$-core of $G$ to be $O_{p^{\prime}}(G)$, the largest normal subgroup of $G$ of order co prime to $p$. Certainly when $p = 2$, the largest normal subgroup of $G$ of order prime to $2$ is denoted by $O(G)$ and called the core of $G.$

Anyway, assuming you really do mean the largest normal $p$-subgroup of $G$ when you write $O_{p}(G)$, we have: $O_{p}(G)$ is the intersection of all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$. If $G$ has an Abelian Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ then $O_{p}(G) \neq 1$ if and only if $P \cap P^{g} > 1$ for all $g \in G$. This is a theorem of J. Brodkey, and it does not work in general for non-Abelian Sylow $p$-subgroups. A famous theorem of R. Baer and M Suzuki is that if there is a non-idenity element $x \in G$ such that $\langle x,x^{g} \rangle $ is a $p$-group for all $g \in G$, then $x \in O_{p}(G)$, so that $O_{p}(G) \neq 1.$ When $p =2$, a consequence of this when $p =2$ is that if $t$ is an involution (element of order $2$) which does not invert any non-identity element of odd order, then $t \in O_{2}(G)$.

I could go on, but reading a graduate level group theory text should give you many more examples.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Yes, I mean the largest normal $p$-subgroup of $G$. Is there one (or more) particular group theory book which you would recommend (since a few don't treat $O_p(G)$) ?

Comment: Aschbacher's' book on Finite Groups would be one.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't mention the $Z_p^*$-theorem, @GeoffRobinson! Suppose that $O_{p'}(G)=1$. If $z$ is an element of order $p$ lying in a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$, and $z$ is not $G$-conjugate to any other elements of $P$, then $z$ lies in $Z(G)$. In particular $z\in O_p(G)$. For $p=2$ this is due to Glauberman, but for $p$ odd it only follows from CFSG.

Comment: True. I'm not sure that the odd $Z^*$ theorem is in many of them though. It won't be in Aschbacher, Gorenstein, Suzuki, etc.

Comment: @Geoff Robinson and @ David A. Craven: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Theorem 2 in my preprint ["Group Orders That Imply Existence of Nontrivial Normal $p$-Subgroups"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0312342) shows that if $|G| = p^s m$ and $p \nmid \Gamma(m)$ (defined therein), then either $O_p (G) \ne 1$, or $G$ is not solvable.

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.